# nginx internal_redirect from perl

Tags: http, perl, nginx, redirect

I am trying to use the internal_redirect in nginx from within a perl module. My perl looks like so (boiled down to a toy example):

```
 sub handler {
   my $r = shift;
   my $original_uri = $r->uri;
   $new_uri = '/hello/world/?foo=heffe';
   $r->internal_redirect($new_uri);
   return OK;
 }
```

In my nginx I have

```
 location /hello/world {
        perl rewrite::handler;
 }
```

When I send a request I get an nginx error like this:

```
 [error] 29#29: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/hello/world/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client:
```

Why does it try to serve a file? How do I just redirect to hello/world?foo=heffe ?

Comment: Have you checked that the file `/etc/nginx/html/hello/world/index.html` exists?

Comment: The error is that the file is not found so I am sure it is not there. This is in a docker context and I am just curling to the endpoint

Comment: Wouldn't `/hello/world/?foo=heffe` mean the same as `/hello/world/index.html?foo=heffe` ? So you will need the file index.html

Comment: I have an appserver running on port 5000 that I want to forward to, how do I do that? I want to redirect to http://localhost:5000/hello/world/?foo=heffe from my handler, how can i do that?